# weighted sampling without repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The general question is: in a problem of weighted sampling without repetition, is there a general formula for computing the probability that the first draw of $X$ is $Y$ and the first draw of $W$ is $Z$?

To make my question more concrete: Suppose there is an urn of 100 balls, labeled 1-100. The probability of ball $n$ being drawn is $p(i)$ (we do not assume that $p(i)=p(j)$ for all $i,j$). Balls $1-25$ are colored Red, balls $26-50$ are colored Yellow, $51-75$ are colored Purple and the rest are colored Black. Balls are drawn from the urn without replacement. So in the end, each draw gives us a sequence of numbers from 1 to 100. The probability of each sequence $x=(x_1,\dots, x_{100})$, is given by
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{100}\frac{p(x_k)}{1-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}p(x_j)}
$$
(assuming $\sum_{j=1}^0p(x_j)=0$). I'm interested in calculating probabilities such as *the probability that the first draw of a yellow-or-black ball is yellow, and the first draw of a red-or-black ball is black.* I got stuck on calculating it by brute force, and was curious if there are shortcuts. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that one event you are describing or two?   If it is a single event (so that, in your draws, a Yellow precedes a black and a black precedes a red) then it is clear that the first draw must be yellow.  After that, the yellow draws are irrelevant and it's easy to compute the probability that black precedes red.

Comment: @lulu Ah sorry the illustrating example is probably too simple. I was thinking one event, and you're totally right the probability of that is easy. But I was thinking that does not generalize. I've changed the example to four colors...(but maybe I'm missing something obvious)

Comment: Adding new colors that don't figure in the events doesn't change anything.  Those draws are irrelevant, you can just ignore those colors.

Comment: If you want something more complicated, you'll need to involve several draws of a single color.  That gets messy fast because now it matters *which* of the Yellow balls you got first (for example).  Keeping track of all the various cases will probably require automation of the computation.

Comment: @lulu Ah that's what I got stuck on. I was thinking adding colors don't matter, i.e.~the probability of a yellow preceding a black, and a black preceeding a black in the original urn (with purple balls), is the same as the probability of that event in an urn where the purple balls are removed and probabilities renormalized...but I haven't figured out how to prove it.

Comment: Just imagine that you are drawing out all $100$ in some order.  Now ignore those colors and just look at the draw you have for the relevant colors.  That's all that matters for the problem and you can analyze it just based on the relevant colors.

Comment: @lulu yeah...but it's not rigorous enough for my purposes...after all getting YBPR is not the same as getting YPBR (since we are not assuming uniform probability). But somehow, as you said, where we insert P should not be relevant...

Comment: So, make my sketched argument rigorous.  Just argue that  each draw of the relevant colors occurs with the same probability that you'd get if you only considered the relevant colors.  You can argue that directly or by an induction on the number of balls.

Comment: Again, if you want to make the problem hard, consider several draws of the same color.  Computing the probability that the first $5$ draws are $YYYBB$ is messy.  Not difficult, really...it's clear what you need to do.  But there are $\binom {25}3=2300$ unordered triples of yellow balls, each with its own probability.

Comment: I would have thought that the probability that "first draw of a yellow-or-black ball is yellow" is $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i \in \text{yellows}}p(i)}{\sum\limits_{i \in \text{yellows}}p(i)+ \sum\limits_{j \in \text{blacks}}p(j)}$; the reds and purples do not affect this - indeed the $p(i)$ can be treated simply as weights $w(i)$ which do not need to sum to $1$ and your expression for the probability of the sequence rewritten as $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{100}\dfrac{w(x_k)}{\sum_{j=k}^{100}w(x_j)}$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the status of this question is now. It seems there was agreement above that the answer to the question as currently posed (asking for "the probability that the first draw of a yellow-or-black ball is yellow, and the first draw of a red-or-black ball is black") is trivial? If you want to be able to handle less trivial cases, you should edit the question to provide a non-trivial example you're interested in.